# Adding array objects to a JSON with a property name in powershell

Tags: json, powershell, api, rest

I've to retrieve products and it's details and save it together in a json file. Unfortunately the name and details cannot be retrieved from the same API, I gotta use 2 different API. So I run a code inside a for loop to retrieve the list of product names as well as its details as follows:

```
For($i=0; $i -lt $cart.total; $i++)
{
$query = 'dummy value with the cart number'
$productName = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://abc' -Body $query -Method Post
$details = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://xyz' -Body $query -Method Post
}
```

All this works, and below is sample data in $productname and $details.

- $productName

"iPhone"

- $details

  "data":[
  {"Moduleid": "1", "propertyName": "camera", "value": "12MP"},
  {"Moduleid" : "43", "propertyName":"battery", "value": "4000MAj"}
  ]

However what I am trying to do is to save the $productName and $details into a json as follows:

```
{
 "iPhone 7":[
{"Moduleid": "1", "propertyName": "camera", "value": "12MP"}, 
{"Moduleid" : "423", "propertyName":"battery", "value": "3000MAh"}
],
 "S10+": [
{"Moduleid": "21", "propertyName": "camera", "value": "12MP"}, 
{"Moduleid" : "43", "propertyName":"battery", "value": "4000MAh"}
]
}
```

I've tried several ways but couldn't reach any conclusion. Please let me know how can these to variable datas be put into a json format as shown above.

Thank you

Comment: Is there any link between the resulting `$productName` and the `$details` to match them together?

Comment: @Theo Just the order :(
When you call the cart number in the query, it'll give list of products and its details in the order in which it is stored.

Comment: Please can you tell us if [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63758798/9898643) works? It looks to me he has it correct. If not, please show us examples of the json results from both queries so we know what we're dealing with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question doesn't make clear what each query is returning.  Generally speaking, you need to convert the return JSON from both queries into objects then merge the objects into the objects you really want.  The run those objects through `ConvertTo-Json` which should do the trick.  The source object structure is what results in the JSON text etc...

It would look something like below, but again, I have to guess at the starting point, for example I'm sure that $productName isn't a flat array, but is itself JSON.

```
# For test
$productName = "iPhone","S10+"

# For test
$details = 
@"
{
    "Data": [{    
        "Moduleid": "1", 
        "propertyName": "camera", 
        "value": "12MP"
    },
    {
        "Moduleid" : "43", 
        "propertyName": "battery", 
        "value": "4000MAj"
    }]
    }
"@ | 
ConvertFrom-Json 

$Results =
For( $i = 0; $i -lt $productName.count; ++$i )
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        $productName[$i] = $details.data[$i]
    }
}

$Results | ConvertTo-Json
```

This would give back:

```
[
    {
        "iPhone":  {
                       "Moduleid":  "1",
                       "propertyName":  "camera",
                       "value":  "12MP"
                   }
    },
    {
        "S10+":  {
                     "Moduleid":  "43",
                     "propertyName":  "battery",
                     "value":  "4000MAj"
                 }
    }
]
```

Not quite what you're looking for, but should at least demonstrate the point.

> Note: Normally I would look for a common property between the 2
> returns to relate the data. Absent that I used the array index.  Again
> part of the reason this doesn't look right.

If you can please edit the question to include the return JSON from both queries, then we can refine the above.

Comment: I created a hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

I created a hashtable like:

```
$hashTable = [HashTable]::New(0, [StringComparer]::Ordinal)
```

This is so that the keys are case sensitive. Normally if you create it as @{}, it won't be case sensitive.

Then i mapped the key and value to the hash table as follows,

```
$hashTable.Add($productName.data.name,$details.data)
```

Now, I convert it to Json as I wanted it using `ConvertTo-Json`

```
$hashTable| ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $outputPath
```